# Using NSSet vs NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, nsset

I understand that there is a difference in how elements are stored in a NSSet and a NSDictionary, 
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Collections.html

But from a development point of view, when should I use NSSet vs NSDictionary? 
The time complexity for both is O(1)

**Edit**: I came across the question - Remove duplicates from an array.
One solution stored the elements in a NSDictionary to remove duplicates, the other solution stored the elements in a NSSet.

I was wondering which would be a better approach

Comment: do you have key-value pairs or not?

Comment: `NSSet` and `NSDictionary` are very differents. `NSSet` is a set of elements when `NSDictionary` will keep a list of pairs `Key-Values`, you can access the `Value` directly when you have the `Key`. It's more logic to compare `NSSet` and `NSArray` the `NSSet` and `NSDictionary`.

Comment: @bsarr007: Since this is an answer and not a comment, why not turn it into an answer?

Comment: From development point of view, you should use the collection that models a solution for your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Take some working code using an NSDictionary. Then replace the NSDictionary with an NSSet. See what happens. Enlightenment should follow.

What good is time complexity if it doesn't work?

Comment: I have seen code in which NSDictionary can be replaced by NSSet. That is the reason I asked the question in the first place.
e.g1 - code that removes duplicates, either collection can be used
e.g2 - code that counts elements in array, can be stored as key-value pairs in a Dictionary or a NSCountedSet can be used

Answer (score 4):

`NSSet` and `NSDictionary` are very different. `NSSet` is a set of elements meanwhile `NSDictionary` keeps a list of key-value pairs, so you can access the `Value` directly when you have the Key. It's more meaningful to compare `NSSet` to `NSArray` than to `NSDictionary`.

Comment: I would say that it is more meaningful to compare `NSArray` to `NSDictionary`, because array indexes are akin of keys. However, comparing collections that are completely different to access can only be compared to underline the differences.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad i agree with you but it depends on the problem you want to solve, you can use an `NSArray` (NSMutableArray) with or without index access for elements(like containsObject, removeObject). When you use indexes you are closer to `NSDictionary`, when you don't, you are closer to `NSSet`.

Comment: It is true that the Cocoa classes are not all fully featured. But I would always prefer an `NSSet`, if I do not have indexed access.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad i want to say both answers are correct, why not write your comment as an answer?